# How to set multiple acceptable value for phpunit assert

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I use Phpunit in Laravel and my Api has multiple acceptable responses. I have problem in 2 case:

**1-** response structure **can be one** of these two:

```
$response->assertJsonStructure(['cities'=>[]]);  

or

$response->assertJsonStructure(['cities'=>[['id','name']]])
```

**2-** response status can be 200 or 302

```
$response->assertStatus(200);

or

$response->assertStatus(302);
```

But I can't find any method to "OR" these two conditions.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$response->assertOr(
    $response->assertStatus(200),
    $response->assertStatus(302)
);
```

Answer (score 7):

for **#1** If you think the value could be empty, just match the key with `assertArrayHasKey()`

```
$response->assertArrayHasKey('cities', $response->getContent());
```

for **#2** You can use `assertContains()` Like

```
 $response->assertContains($response->getStatusCode(), array(200,302));
```

Here you can find about more. https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/assertions.html#assertcontains

Comment: thank Vikash  But this not answering for my first case problem!

Comment: @Sadegh check the solution now.

Comment: this not check the structure of response! and if I want to check structure separately I need an "OR" condition again!

Comment: In such case you can  you should use `->assertTrue($this->yourcustomfunction($response))` and define the `yourcustomfunction` with all your custome code.

Answer (score 1):

for 2º case you can use like

```html
if($response->getStatusCode() == 410) {
  $response->assertStatus(410);
} else {
  $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this to my base `TestCase` class:

```php
/**
 * Assert that at least one of the `callable`s pass (short-circuiting)
 * @param array<callable> $callables
 * @return void
 */
public function assertOr(array $callables, int $minimum = 1): void {
    $this->assertGreaterThanOrEqual(1, $minimum);
    $passCount = 0;

    foreach ($callables as $callable) {
        $passes = true;
        try {
            $callable();
        } catch (ExpectationFailedException $e) {
            $passes = false;
        }
        $passCount += (int) $passes;
        if ($passCount >= $minimum) {
            break;
        }
    }

    $this->assertGreaterThanOrEqual($minimum, $passCount);
}
```